# getting syntax error: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Tags: python, excel

am getting below error when am trying to fetch the value of excel sheet for both row and cloumn.

```
import openpyxl
import os
os.chdir('I:\\testing')


workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook('sync_check.xlsx')

sheet=workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    for i in range(17, 2):
        print (i, str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2)).value)  
    exit();
```

below are the error which am receiving while running.

> SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

your help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about the error you mention, but the code you've shared should generate an `IndentationError`. Please fix it. We can't magically figure out which errors are relevant and which are typos.

Comment: Given that the code you show *has* no triple-quoted string literals, I'm immediately worried about what `openpyxl` is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Provide a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem. Can you reproduce the problem by making a single call to `sheet.cell` with a hard-coded `row` (and if so, what are the contents of the cell)? Is the loop even running, or is the error being raised by `get_sheet_by_name` or even `load_workbook`?

Comment: Change to `... column=2).value))`. Note the moved **`)`** to the end.

Comment: @stovfl i tried but still same

Comment: @Chris am not getting any IndentationError but am getting below one.
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Comment: @Rahul: [Edit] your Question and show the **Full Traceback**

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I gathered that. But why does it appear to be trying to parse Python code? (Unless you have a triple-quoted string in *your* code that you aren't showing.)

Comment: I asked you three hours ago to provide a complete, minimal example. We don't have your spreadsheet to test on (assuming the spreadsheet is even the problem).

Comment: @chepner i do have string value in my excel sheet. might be that is the problem